# from_port and to_port values for icmp protocol ingress rule aws_security_group resource?

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I want to setup an ingress "Custome ICMP (IPv4)" rule for a security group, and the [aws_security_group](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/security_group) page isn't clear on what I need to put for the `from_port` and `to_port` values. It says (similar for the `to_port`)

```
from_port - (Required) The start port (or ICMP type number if protocol is "icmp" or "icmpv6")
```

What is `ICMP type number`? If I do this manually in the AWS console, the port is defaulted to `N/A`.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can get the ICMP type number from this site

https://www.iana.org/assignments/icmp-parameters/icmp-parameters.xhtml

Assuming you want to allow a ping (Echo) to your server you can use the following terraform configuration

```
from_port = 8
to_port = 0
protocol = "icmp"
```

If you want to allow all ICMP you can use the following configuration:

```
from_port = -1
to_port = -1
protocol = "icmp"
```

Which was sourced from this blog:

https://blog.jwr.io/terraform/icmp/ping/security/groups/2018/02/02/terraform-icmp-rules.html

Comment: Why is it 8 to 0 instead of 0 to 8?

Comment: [ICMP type is 8, and echo is code 0](https://www.iana.org/assignments/icmp-parameters/icmp-parameters.xhtml#icmp-parameters-codes-8); terraform provider wants [icmp type mapped to from_port and code mapped to to_port](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/security_group#ingress).